# Как использовать Skype Web SDK?

Tags: javascript, skype, skype-web-sdk

Товарищи инженеры, помогите разобраться. На сайте [UCWA](https://ucwa.skype.com/index) есть официальные примеры для скачивания и подключения к Skype Web SDK через HTML/JS скрипты, и ссылка на [статью по использованию примеров localhost only](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/07/how-to-skype-web-sdk-development-without-having-all-the-server-pre-requisites-in-place/). Отдельным пунктом значится `Configure a Web Server such as IIS on your local machine to serve the files`. Исходя из этого, я понял что для использования требуется Microsoft Lync Server 2013, в котором нужно прописать домен с размещенными скриптами для подключения к Web SDK. На данный момент при попытке авторизироваться по domain/token браузер Chrome пытается отправить запросы: `https://lyncdiscoverinternal.metio.net/xframe` в ответ `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`; `https://lyncdiscover.metio.net/xframe` в ответ `403 (Forbidden)`. После я получаю текст ошибок:

```
Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin.
Autodiscovery failed on internal/external location
```

Comment: то же самое. Нашел ветку на их форуме https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4df60368-e65c-4d01-821c-f929a2b4dd5b/403-forbidden-access-is-denied-when-logging-into-skype-for-business?forum=SkypeWebSDK - Но в общем-то это не спасло.